# Summation of signless Stirling numbers of first kind

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers, permutation-cycles

This is from 
Discrete mathematics and its application by Kenneth H Rosen

> The signless Stirling number of the first kind $c(n,k)$ where $k$ and
>   $n$ are integers with $1\leq k\leq n$, equals the number of ways to
>   arrange $n$ people around $k$ circular tables with at least one person
>   seated at each table, where two seatings of m people around a circular
>   table are considered same if everyone has the same left neighbor and
>   the same right neighbor. Then prove  $\sum_{j=1}^nc(n,j)=n!$ if $n$ is
>   a positive integer

I know $c(n,n)=1$,$c(n,n-1)=n_{C_2}$,$c(n,1)=n-1!$
But I don't know how to prove the summation.

Comment: $c(n,k)$ is the number of permutations of $n$ elements with $k$ disjoint cycles.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind

Comment: Yes I know that but can you please help me how to prove the summation

Comment: Well, every permutation has a unique expression as a product of disjoint cycles. And you know how many permutations of $n$ elements there are, right, Ashok?

Comment: Still can't get it. I am totally naive in this field. Can you explain me in easy way

Comment: Look at my comment, Ashok. Look at Robert's comment. Put them together. What do they tell you about summing $c(n,k)$ over all $k$? By the way, in the summation in your question, you have a sum over $j$ of a function that doesn't have $j$ in it. Probably you meant for that $j$ to be $k$. You could edit that to be correct.

Comment: Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 0):

@GerryMyerson i solved it with induction. Please check if it is correct

Base case: n=1 $\sum_{j=1}^1c(n,j)=1!$ which holds true because there is only one way to sit one person on one circular table.

Let  P(n) holds. Now there is [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation) followed by c(n,k), which is $c(n + 1, k) = c(n, k − 1) + nc(n, k)$

Now for P(n+1) $\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}c(n+1,j)$=$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}(c(n,j-1)+n*c(n,j))$

=$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}c(n,j-1)$+$n*\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}c(n,j)$

Now let j-1=i so first sum becomes
$\sum_{i=0}^{n}c(n,i)$+$n*\sum_{j=1}^{n}c(n,j)+n*c(n,n+1)$
now when i=0 c(n,0)=0 and also c(n,n+1)=0. So

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}c(n,i)$+n*n! because P(n) is true.

=n!+n*n!=n+1!. So P(n+1) is also true. Hence proved

Comment: Putting @Gerry in an answer doesn't notify me, it has to be in a comment, in a stream of comments where I have been active. Your proof might work, but it is way too much work. $c(n,k)$ is the number of permutations of $n$ elements with $k$ disjoint cycles, so $\sum_{j=1}^nc(n,j)$ is the number of permutations of $n$ elements with one cycle, plus the number of permutations of $n$ elements with two cycles, plus ... plus the number of permutations of $n$ elements with $n$ cycles, which is the total number of permutations, which is $n$-factorial. QED

Comment: Gerry Myerson's comment means the same as what the book solution says.